# R: How to remove a part of string, which with a specific start and end, in a R dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```r
df = data.frame(order = c(1,2,3), info = c("an apple","a banana[12],","456[Ab]"))
```

I want to clean up to remove the `[]` and content inside `[]`. So that the result of df$info will be "an apple" "a banana" "456"

Please help...

Answer (score 3):

Use `gsub`:

```r
df$info <- gsub("\\[.*?\\]", "", df$info)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I google you an answer. May I ask .*? mean than everything inside the [ ] will be cleared ? If next time I just want to remove the one with digit inside  "[" and "]", e.g. [12] is removed while [Ab] is kept. What should I do?

Comment: To target just bracket terms containing digits, use `\[\d+\]`

Comment: Oh. I do it. gsub("\\[[[1-9]*?\\]", "", df$info)
gsub("\\[[^[1-9]*?\\]", "", df$info)

Comment: Do you need the `?` to make * "lazy"? I think `"\\[.*\\]"` covers case where you have empty brackets `[]` and with something after. Is there something else?

Comment: @AndrewBrown Consider `[Ab]456[Cd]` ... without lazy dot, `\[.*\]` would match the entire string.

Comment: Sorry guys, May I ask any way to remove the bracket with just consist of letter? I find " gsub("\\[[^[1-9]*?\\]", "", df$info)" but seems not a formal..

Comment: Use: `\[[A-Za-z]+\]`

Answer (score 2):

**1.)** This will give the expected output with removing also the comma:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(info = str_trim(str_replace_all(info, "(\\[.*\\])\\,?", "")))
```

```
  order     info
1     1 an apple
2     2 a banana
3     3      456
```

**2.)** This will remove brackets and their content:

`\\[`....match `[`

`.*`....any following characters

`\\]`... match `]`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(info = str_replace_all(info, "\\[.*\\]$", ""))
```

```
  order      info
1     1  an apple
2     2 a banana,
3     3       456
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can use `trimws`

```
df$info <- trimws(df$info, whitespace = "\\[.*")
df$info
[1] "an apple" "a banana" "456"
```